# Why do these triangle symbols mean?

Tags: schematics

In configuration B in the image below, what do the triangles mean?

[image]

Comment: They mean greater then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Delta symbol can be read as "Difference". So for example in chart B, to move the motor Forward: IN1 > IN2 (And Difference > 15), the PWM number must be at least 15 higher for IN1.

Also notice that in Chart A the motor runs from 15 to 255 (below 15 it does not run), so in chart B it shows that Halt is when IN1=IN2 or Difference < 15.

Backwards is similar to Forward except of course IN1 < IN2, and the Difference > 15.